# Bayesian posterior distributions

Tags: bayesian

I have the model $y_{i,t}=x_{i,t}'\beta_{i} + \epsilon_{i,t}$ where $x_{i,t}$ is a k-dimensional vector of explanatory variables and $\beta_{i}$ is a k-dimensional parameter vector, where $\beta_{i}=\Gamma'w_{i}+\eta_{i}$ where $w_{i}$ is an l-dimensional vector of explanatory variables and $\Gamma$ is a $l\times k$ parameter matrix. 
Assuming that $\epsilon_{i,t} \sim N(0,\sigma_{\epsilon}^{2})$ and $\eta_{i} \sim N(0,\Sigma_{\eta})$ and also assuming uninformative priors for the parameters $\sigma_{\epsilon}^{2}, \Sigma_{\eta}, \beta_{i}$ and $\Gamma$ I cannot seem to find their posterior distributions. Any help ? The reason I need their posterior distributions is to use Gibbs sampling later to estimate them.

Comment: what values can $i$ and $t$ take on?

Comment: Does it matter ? $i$ can take the values 1,2,...,4000 and $t=1,2,...,31$

Answer (score 1):

This is a hierarchical or linear mixed model. Be careful about using improper noninformative priors in this context since they often (not always) lead to improper posteriors. See for instance:

> Hobert, James P., and George Casella. "[The effect of improper priors on Gibbs sampling in hierarchical linear mixed models](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1996.10476714)." Journal of the American Statistical Association 91.436 (1996): 1461-1473.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to sample from the corresponding posterior distribution. Also, you need the conditionals, rather than the posteriors, in order to implement a Gibbs sampler.

Some useful are packages for sampling from the posterior associated to this kind of models are `spBayes` (adaptive Metropolis within Gibbs) and `MCMCglmm` (block Gibbs sampler).

Comment: In Gibbs sampling the posteriors of one parameter are conditional on the other parameters in any case. I would like to hardcode it, so without the use of the package :). If I find the posteriors analytically then I can draw from them. It is just that I cannot find any literature on this :(